# Date processing in Java

Tags: java, date

I have 2 strings which are actually dates but they are in different format:

1. 2004-06-01 00:00:00 (This value I get from Excel database through JDBC)
2. 6/1/2004

Is their any pre-defined Class in Java which I can use to create Date kind of object? So that I can just invoke its constructor over these Strings and finally compare them.

Or will I have to write my own function to compare using String functions? Please Help.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

SimpleDateFormat is an implementation of the abstract [DateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html). You first define the pattern of the date in the constructor and then use parse method.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
```

If you are using a Locale other than the default, you need to define it at the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `Date` constructor that accepts an arbitrarily formatted string, but you could write a method easily enough:

```
Date parseDate(String dateFormat, String dateValue) throws ParseException {
    return new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).parse(dateValue);
}
```

Usage:

```
Date myExcelDate = parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "2004-06-01 00:00:00");
Date myOtherDate = parseDate("d/M/yyyy", "6/1/2004");
```

You'll need to catch a potential ParseException. See [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for format string details.

Answer (score 2):

If you get a "Date String" from JDBC, you're doing something wrong - use [ResultSet.getDate()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate(int)).